# How do you vectorise a loop?

Tags: c, optimization, parallel-processing, vectorization, cluster-computing

I'm having trouble in vectorising a loop. I'm looking to rewrite the code below such that it is vectorised. I have ran Complete Banerjee's test and I have found that all dependencies are broken but I don't know where to go from here.
The compiler is gcc. The architecture is x86 and the arrays are integer arrays.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
     x[20 + i] = y[i] * z[i];
     p[i] = x[21 + i] + q[i];
}
```

Comment: Vectorization is generally an optimization that you rely upon your compiler to perform for you.  The C language does not have a means to express "this loop should be vectorized", though it may be that your particular implementation provides an extension that serves the purpose.

Comment: eg: `gcc -ftree-vectorize ...`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?  Are you asking what compiler switches to use to ask the compiler to vectorize (you didn't say what compiler you are using), or what changes to make to your code to encourage the compiler to do so effectively (still compiler-dependent), or how to rewrite the code yourself in assembly language with vector instructions (you didn't say what CPU)?  In any case, more information is needed.

Comment: @NateEldredge My apologies. What I meant was how to rewrite in C such that it is vectorised. I'll make the edit now!

Comment: Also, why the [tag:parallel-processing] and [tag:cluster-computing] tags?  These generally refer to dividing a computation among multiple threads / processes / jobs which can then be run in parallel on multiple cores / CPUs / computers.  But vectorization keeps the computation in a single thread on a single core, only asking that core to use instructions that process several data elements at once.

Comment: You could be interested in [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) or [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC) or [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) or [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). But do read about [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) optimization abilities

Comment: So, you need to say the compiler you are using (including version), the particular architecture you are targeting (including extensions such as x86's SSE, AVX, etc), and also the type(s) of the arrays `x,y,z,p,q`.

Comment: @NateEldredge My apologies! I made the amendments up there.

Comment: Can you please reread my last comment?  Compiler **including version** and architecture **including extensions** (and in particular I'm assuming this is to be 64-bit code).  And what size of integer?

Comment: As one hint, the second line of the loop doesn't read any data written by the first.  It seems to help the compiler if you interchange the two lines ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/fEqG79)), or even move the second line to its own loop which runs first.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't mean to be rude but what degree of importance is it? The problem I was specified with is a theory problem, I was presented with the problem but I gave the specs as if it were my own machine.

Comment: Well, if you're asking at a theoretical level what changes *might* help a *hypothetical* compiler to vectorize the code, you can ask that, but the answers will be vague.  Some hypothetical compilers might be able to vectorize it just fine in its current form.  If you want to know how to get a *real* compiler to do so, the answer may depend on how that compiler is implemented, and what machine instructions are available to it.  [...]

Comment: And the best way to check is by actually compiling the code and looking at the generated assembly.  So I can do that, but if I'm using a totally different compiler or architecture than you are, my results may not be very helpful to you.  Thus if your goal is to actually be able to compile and run this loop as vectorized code on an actual machine, then the specifics are important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two general tips:

- Pass the arrays as parameters to your function, using the `restrict` keyword to inform the compiler that they cannot alias one another (which would prevent any vectorization).
- Although the read from `x` on the second line of your loop does not depend on the write on the first line, the compiler may not be smart enough to detect that.  Help it out by interchanging those two lines, or by moving the read to its own loop before the write.

The following version is successfully vectorized by gcc 10.2 with `-O3 -march-skylake` ([try on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/q5WxGP)), using ymm registers to process 8 `int`s per iteration.  It also unrolls the loop completely since the iteration count is constant and not too large.

```
void foo(
            int *restrict x,
            const int *restrict y,
            const int *restrict z,
            int *restrict p,
            const int *restrict q
        ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
        p[i] = x[21 + i] + q[i];
        x[20 + i] = y[i] * z[i];
    }
}
```